# I need help simplifying and reorganizing this algebraic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've developed the following algebraic equation which could probably be simplified further.  Also, I need it reorganized to solve for x and Y (in terms of A, x, and Y.  Not looking for a numerical answer to x or Y).  Any takers?

$$
A=0.0193(\frac{x+0.05}{0.05})^2+0.0876(\frac{x+0.05}{0.05})+(\frac{Y}{0.2}(0.75+0.028(\frac{x+0.05}{0.05})))+1.356
$$

Comment: It indeed can be simplified. For example $\dfrac{x + 0.05}{0.05} = 20x + 1.$ But what do you mean by "solve" for $x, Y.$ We have 1 equation in 3 unknowns: $x, Y, A.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A = x(8.106x + 2.8Y + 17.906) + 3.89Y + 2.2513$

$\large Y = \frac{10A - 81.06x^2 - 176.06x - 22.513}{28x + 38.9}$

$x$ is not at all pretty, so I'll just [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=A+%3D+x%288.106x%2B2.8y%2B17.906%29%2B3.89y%2B2.2513%2C+solve+for+x) you to it.

I hope that's what you wanted.

Comment: I must have confused my formula above somehow.  Here it is in plain text:  A=(0.0193*((x+0.05)/0.05)^2)+(0.0876*((x+0.05)/0.05))+SUM(1.356,(Y/0.2*(0.75+(0.028*((x+0.05)/0.05)))))

Comment: Your simplification comes to A = 2.2513 when I plug in x = 0 and Y = 0, whereas mine comes to A = 1.46

Comment: Yep, I mistyped 0.876 when it should be 0.0876.  My apologies!